# Can anyone identify this encoding?

Tags: python, delphi, character-encoding, escaping

Im working on a program to interface with some hardware that is sending data that has been encoded  and wrapped to send within a CDATA block in an XML document.

the software in the device as far as I know is written in Python and i'm writing the interface in Delphi.

the data the device sends is this

> \x00E\x18\x10\x14}*UF!A\x81\xac\x08&\x02\x01\n\x15\x1a\xc2PP\x92\x17\xc2\xc1\xa0\x0e\x1a\xc2\xd0K\x94\'\x830\x11\x8b
>   \x84a_\xa0+\x04\x81\x17\x89\x15D\x91B\x05.\x84\xf1\x1b\x89%E\x00\x04\x9c\x0e\xc5\xc1=\x87\x0bE\xf18\x07\x1f\xc8a\xa5\x95\x08H\x80?\x84\x18\tPK\x8a$\t\xf1\xb2\x8e(J\xb0\x08\x91\x1eJ\xf0W\x0c-\x0b\xf0\x0e\x88\x07\x0c\x00\x9b\n
>   \x910Z\x06!\x92\xf0W\x073S
>   \x08\x87\xff\xff\xff\xf0\x0e\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf3\x10\x0e\xba\xff\xff\xff\xf4C
>   \xed\xbb\xb9_\xffDD1\r\xcb\xbaw\xf5TD2\xed\xbb\xba\x88EUDB\x0c\xba\xaa\x99UUDB\x0c\xba\xaa\xa9UUD2\r\xbb\xaa\xaaUTD2\r\xcb\xbb\xaaUTC!\r\xcb\xbb\xbbUD3!\x0e\xdc\xbb\xbbDD3!\x0e\xdc\xcc\xbbDC2!\x0e\xdc\xcc\xcc33"\x11\x0e\xdd\xcc\xccC3"\x11\x0e\xed\xdc\xcc\xf33!\x10\x0e\xee\xdd\xcc\xf32!\x10\x0e\xee\xdd\xdc\xff2!\x10\x00\xee\xee\xdd\xff\xf2!\x11\x00\x0e\xee\xdd\xff\xf2!\x11\x10\x0e\xee\xef\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00

I need to be able to send similar data back to the device but the format i have it in is this

> 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

I know that \x is usually used to represent ascii chars using their hex values in 2 digit pairs but looking at the data this not the case. i'm struggling to identify the encoding used and the manufacturer is not providing much help.

what I want to know is how do I convert the hex I have to the format they are using in Delphi xe4?

**BTW the two block do not contain the same data but it is the same type of data ie the format is the same just different encoding**

example of the data being sent

```
POST ******** HTTP/1.1 Host: 172.16.1.136:8080 Accept-Encoding: identity Content-Length: 1552 Content-Type: text/xml Authorization: 1344354:PASS User-Agent: *********

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Biometrics>   <Templates>
     <Template badge="1075" readerType="6" index="6" ts="2014-11-06T17:28:40.000+01:00" chk="3a6a4924ec04e668186b15e244e6fe73">   <![CDATA[     ['1075_6',
1415294920.3754971, [0, 0], [['3\x04\x00\x00\x00P\x00\x00E\x18\x10\x14}*UF!A\x81\xac\x08&\x02\x01\n\x15\x1a\xc2PP\x92\x17\xc2\xc1\xa0\x0e\x1a\xc2\xd0K\x94\'\x830\x11\x8b \x84a_\xa0+\x04\x81\x17\x89\x15D\x91B\x05.\x84\xf1\x1b\x89%E\x00\x04\x9c\x0e\xc5\xc1=\x87\x0bE\xf18\x07\x1f\xc8a\xa5\x95\x08H\x80?\x84\x18\tPK\x8a$\t\xf1\xb2\x8e(J\xb0\x08\x91\x1eJ\xf0W\x0c-\x0b\xf0\x0e\x88\x07\x0c\x00\x9b\n \x910Z\x06!\x92\xf0W\x073S \x08\x87\xff\xff\xff\xf0\x0e\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf3\x10\x0e\xba\xff\xff\xff\xf4C \xed\xbb\xb9_\xffDD1\r\xcb\xbaw\xf5TD2\xed\xbb\xba\x88EUDB\x0c\xba\xaa\x99UUDB\x0c\xba\xaa\xa9UUD2\r\xbb\xaa\xaaUTD2\r\xcb\xbb\xaaUTC!\r\xcb\xbb\xbbUD3!\x0e\xdc\xbb\xbbDD3!\x0e\xdc\xcc\xbbDC2!\x0e\xdc\xcc\xcc33"\x11\x0e\xdd\xcc\xccC3"\x11\x0e\xed\xdc\xcc\xf33!\x10\x0e\xee\xdd\xcc\xf32!\x10\x0e\xee\xdd\xdc\xff2!\x10\x00\xee\xee\xdd\xff\xf2!\x11\x00\x0e\xee\xdd\xff\xf2!\x11\x10\x0e\xee\xef\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00']]] ]]> </Template>

  </Templates> </Biometrics> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 Content-Type: text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Date: Thu, 06 Nov 2014 17:28:41 GMT

52 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><OperationStatus uid="">OK</OperationStatus> 0
```

These are biometric templates used by the Suprema Reader if that helps.

**Solution**

I have successfully deciphered what is going on with this now. to turn my original hex string into the required format I'm using this code, hope this helps someone else in the future. Please feel free to comment and make suggestions to improve the code.

```
class function TConvert.HexToPythonEscAscii(const aHexString: string): string;
var
  i: Integer;
  ByteArray: array of Byte;
begin
  Result := '';

  SetLength(ByteArray, (length(aHexString) div 2) );

  TConvert.HexToBytes(aHexString, ByteArray, length(ByteArray));

  for i := Low(ByteArray) to High(ByteArray) do
  begin
    if ByteArray[i] in [$20..$7E] then
    begin

      case ByteArray[i] of
        $5c : Result := Result +'\\';
        $27 : Result := Result +'\''';
      else
        Result := Result + char(ByteArray[i])
      end;

    end
    else
    begin

      case ansichar(ByteArray[i]) of
        TAB : Result :=  Result + '\t';
        LF  : Result :=  Result + '\n';
        CR  : Result :=  Result + '\r';
      else
        Result :=  Result + '\x' + LowerCase(IntToHex(ByteArray[i], 2));
      end;

    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It sounds like a question for http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Looks like binary rather than encoded text. What do the docs say?

Comment: As for the \x that is just a byte represented as hex. Everything else is ascii.

Comment: docs say this but its clearly wrong "data should be sent in ASCII.  If a template is binary, it should be Base64 encoded"

Comment: Ive had these comments back from the manufacturer 

"I think its a bit relative; the individual characters are expressed at UTF-8, though they could combine to represent larger UTF-16 elements, but as presented can be done really with any character set.  Unfortunately some environments or languages make handling unicode easier than others; ours its native, not so much in others.  So for us it is easily converted to a simple ASCII string.  Each char is still an ord() 0..255 so can be read/written in ascii, hex or unicode."

Comment: The data you have matches none of that! Humph.

Comment: Well, if you don't know **in detail** what the received data structure is you'll never be able to map the encoded data to the data structure, and likewise you won't be able to send your data out in the required structure. So that's to be solved first and only the manufacturer or original programmers can tell you. The decoding is not the issue, the required data structure is.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This looks like binary data held in a Python `bytes` object. Loosely, bytes that map to printable ASCII characters are presented as those ASCII characters. All other bytes are encoded `\x**` where `**` is the hex representation of the byte.

```
>>> b = b'\x00E\x18\x10\x14}*UF!A\x81\xac\x08&\x02\x01\n\x15\x1a\xc2PP\x92'
>>> str(b)
'\x00E\x18\x10\x14}*UF!A\x81\xac\x08&\x02\x01\n\x15\x1a\xc2PP\x92'
>>> ord(b[0])
0
>>> ord(b[1])
69
>>> ord(b[2])
24
>>> ord(b[3])
16
>>> ord(b[4])
20
>>> ord(b[5])
125
>>> ord(b[6])
42
>>> bytes(bytearray((0, 69, 24, 16, 20, 125, 42)))
'\x00E\x18\x10\x14}*'
>>> bytes(bytearray(range(256)))
'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15
\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;?@ABCDEFGHIJKL
MNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86
\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b
\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0
\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5
\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda
\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef
\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
```

The Python documentation describes bytes literals here: https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings

As to what the binary means, I presume that you know that.

Comment: Next question is how do I handle it in Delphi?

Comment: It's pretty easy to parse. If you pull off a `\` then the next character will be `x` and after that two hex digits. That's one byte. Otherwise you have ASCII. If you had a general string then you'd need to cater for octal and other escapes but it looks like this has been formatted by `str()`. You can pull that into a `TBytes` fairly easily right?

Comment: thanks so much im not a python dev and this was really perplexing me. ill give it a bash now.

Comment: Gah comment format messed up. Meant to say "pull off a \"

Comment: just testing it now and ill let you know if you are correct

Comment: if I encode the printable chars using \xhh and their hex value do you think it will it work.

Comment: Yes it will. It will be expensive in terms of size, but it will be understood. I thought you were parsing rather than emitting.

Comment: I'd say it would be worth saving the space by encoding printable ascii the same way python does. Easy enough to replicate that and work out how python does it.

Comment: yeah i'm just being lazy for proof of concept first, then i'll do the extra work to change it.

Answer (score 0):

```html
#!/bin/bash

binary_data=$(echo -n -e "\x00E\x18\x10\x14}*UF!A\x81\xac\x08&\x02\x01\n\x15\x1a\xc2PP\x92\x17\xc2\xc1\xa0\x0e\x1a\xc2\xd0K\x94\'\x830\x11\x8b \x84a_\xa0+\x04\x81\x17\x89\x15D\x91B\x05.\x84\xf1\x1b\x89%E\x00\x04\x9c\x0e\xc5\xc1=\x87\x0bE\xf18\x07\x1f\xc8a\xa5\x95\x08H\x80?\x84\x18\tPK\x8a$\t\xf1\xb2\x8e(J\xb0\x08\x91\x1eJ\xf0W\x0c-\x0b\xf0\x0e\x88\x07\x0c\x00\x9b\n \x910Z\x06!\x92\xf0W\x073S \x08\x87\xff\xff\xff\xf0\x0e\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf3\x10\x0e\xba\xff\xff\xff\xf4C \xed\xbb\xb9_\xffDD1\r\xcb\xbaw\xf5TD2\xed\xbb\xba\x88EUDB\x0c\xba\xaa\x99UUDB\x0c\xba\xaa\xa9UUD2\r\xbb\xaa\xaaUTD2\r\xcb\xbb\xaaUTC!\r\xcb\xbb\xbbUD3!\x0e\xdc\xbb\xbbDD3!\x0e\xdc\xcc\xbbDC2!\x0e\xdc\xcc\xcc33"\x11\x0e\xdd\xcc\xccC3"\x11\x0e\xed\xdc\xcc\xf33!\x10\x0e\xee\xdd\xcc\xf32!\x10\x0e\xee\xdd\xdc\xff2!\x10\x00\xee\xee\xdd\xff\xf2!\x11\x00\x0e\xee\xdd\xff\xf2!\x11\x10\x0e\xee\xef\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\")

echo -n -e "$binary_data" > output_file
```