# python3 The string is converted to be strange

Tags: python-3.6

```
# predefined data
DC_MOTOR_FORWARD = '\xFF\x00'
DC_MOTOR_BACKWARD = '\x00\xFF'
DC_MOTOR_STOP = '\x00\x00'


def name2cmnd_DC_MOTOR(name):
    table = {
        'forward': DC_MOTOR_FORWARD,
        'backward': DC_MOTOR_BACKWARD,
        'stop': DC_MOTOR_STOP
    }
    try:
        return table[name]
    except:
        return 0x00



test = name2cmnd_DC_MOTOR('forward')

print(test)
```

I just want to get out of the string.
However, this strange string "ÿ" comes out.

The string is converted to be strange.

How do I get it to be just a string?

Comment: [check this link stack overflow may be this could help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802581/can-anyone-identify-this-encoding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing out exactly what you've put into your *table* dictionary. xFF (which you've defined in DC_MOTOR_FORWARD) is translated to UTF-16 as [ÿ](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ff/index.htm).

So the question is, what string were you expecting?

Comment: Ah! I did not want to convert my mistake to utf-16, but I wanted to use it as a string. Attaching two backslashes solves this problem.


Anyway, thank you for your kind answer.