# Decoding the following string to get URL

Tags: python, arrays, decoding

I am trying to decode the following string :

`b'\x08\x13"\xc2\xaf\x01https://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/2020/01/11/zingaretti-dopo-le-regionali-sciolgo-il-pd-e-lancio-partito-nuovo-orlando-ragionare-su-come-rifondare-orfini-non-sia-fuffa/5664444/\xc3\x92\x01\xc2\xb3\x01https://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/2020/01/11/zingaretti-dopo-le-regionali-sciolgo-il-pd-e-lancio-partito-nuovo-orlando-ragionare-su-come-rifondare-orfini-non-sia-fuffa/5664444/amp/'`

in Python 3.6 but haven't had any success so far. 
I need to obtain the first link.

I tried decoding with `'cp1252'`, `'UTF-8'`, `'UTF-16'` and a few others but my  attempts were unsuccessful. 
Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: how did you get it? Maybe you should different method to get it.

Comment: it doesn't look like encoding - rather like `compression` or `pickle` or something similar.

Comment: I got it by using urlsafe_b64decode `urlsafe_b64decode` on the following string: `CBMirwFodHRwczovL3d3dy5pbGZhdHRvcXVvdGlkaWFuby5pdC8yMDIwLzAxLzExL3ppbmdhcmV0dGktZG9wby1sZS1yZWdpb25hbGktc2Npb2xnby1pbC1wZC1lLWxhbmNpby1wYXJ0aXRvLW51b3ZvLW9ybGFuZG8tcmFnaW9uYXJlLXN1LWNvbWUtcmlmb25kYXJlLW9yZmluaS1ub24tc2lhLWZ1ZmZhLzU2NjQ0NDQv0gGzAWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmlsZmF0dG9xdW90aWRpYW5vLml0LzIwMjAvMDEvMTEvemluZ2FyZXR0aS1kb3BvLWxlLXJlZ2lvbmFsaS1zY2lvbGdvLWlsLXBkLWUtbGFuY2lvLXBhcnRpdG8tbnVvdm8tb3JsYW5kby1yYWdpb25hcmUtc3UtY29tZS1yaWZvbmRhcmUtb3JmaW5pLW5vbi1zaWEtZnVmZmEvNTY2NDQ0NC9hbXAv`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802581/can-anyone-identify-this-encoding

Comment: using `pickle.dumps("http://...")` you can get similar string `b'\x80\x03X\n\x00\x00\x00http://...q\x00.'` but probably page uses some library in JavaScript with different method to serialize data - and maybe if you check all JavaScript's files on page you can find library and rewrite it in Python or maybe there is already Python's module which works like this JavaScript library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the quick glance I can tell you that binary part is some kind of the header, which contains the information about the data. Not sure about every number in the header, the one before the last byte contains the URL length. For the first URL the length is 0xAF and for the second URL the length is 0xB3:

```
>>> a = 'https://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/2020/01/11/zingaretti-dopo-le-regionali-sciolgo-il-pd-e-lancio-partito-nuovo-orlando-ragionare-su-come-rifondare-orfini-non-sia-fuffa/5664444/'
>>> len(a)
175
>>> hex(len(a))
'0xaf'
>>> b = 'https://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/2020/01/11/zingaretti-dopo-le-regionali-sciolgo-il-pd-e-lancio-partito-nuovo-orlando-ragionare-su-come-rifondare-orfini-non-sia-fuffa/5664444/amp/'
>>> hex(len(b))
'0xb3'
>>>
```

I don't have enough information about the rest of the binary data, and I don't know what happens when URL length is over 255, but for your string analysis I'd recommend to find `http://` string, walk 2 bytes back, read the length and extract the whole URL, then start again from the end of the extracted URL:

```
c = 'your data which I dont copy again, but you should =)'
pos = 0
while True :
    url_start = c.find( 'http', pos )
    if url_start == -1 : break
    url_length = ord(c[url_start - 2])
    print 'start', url_start, 'length', url_length
    print c[url_start:url_start + url_length]
    pos = url_start + url_length
```

that will give you the following output:

```
start 6 length 175
https://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/2020/01/11/zingaretti-dopo-le-regionali-sciolgo-il-pd-e-lancio-partito-nuovo-orlando-ragionare-su-come-rifondare-orfini-non-sia-fuffa/5664444/
start 187 length 179
https://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/2020/01/11/zingaretti-dopo-le-regionali-sciolgo-il-pd-e-lancio-partito-nuovo-orlando-ragionare-su-come-rifondare-orfini-non-sia-fuffa/5664444/amp/
```

ps. if you're using python3, you may use `print( ... )` with parentheses

Answer (score 1):

Your data appears to be a binary string where the odd looking `\x...` components are unicode characters in front of and inside of your binary string. You mentioned you need to obtain the first link and I see two distinct urls in your example.

Running the following code:

```
value = b'\x08\x13"\xc2\xaf\x01https://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/2020/01/11/zingaretti-dopo-le-regionali-sciolgo-il-pd-e-lancio-partito-nuovo-orlando-ragionare-su-come-rifondare-orfini-non-sia-fuffa/5664444/\xc3\x92\x01\xc2\xb3\x01https://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/2020/01/11/zingaretti-dopo-le-regionali-sciolgo-il-pd-e-lancio-partito-nuovo-orlando-ragionare-su-come-rifondare-orfini-non-sia-fuffa/5664444/amp/'
print(value.decode('utf-8'))
```

yields:

```
"¯https://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/2020/01/11/zingaretti-dopo-le-regionali-sciolgo-il-pd-e-lancio-partito-nuovo-orlando-ragionare-su-come-rifondare-orfini-non-sia-fuffa/5664444/Ò³https://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/2020/01/11/zingaretti-dopo-le-regionali-sciolgo-il-pd-e-lancio-partito-nuovo-orlando-ragionare-su-come-rifondare-orfini-non-sia-fuffa/5664444/amp/
```

You now can do whatever string manipulation is needed to obtain the first link.