# Convert a Byte string to hex to something I can read like UTF-8 with python

Tags: python, hex

if you find anything wrong with my question please let me know.

I have a discontinued solar charge controller with a rs232 uart port and I managed to connect it to my pi 3B+ with a rs232 hat.

The problem is that I get data in the form of a byte-string with hex values and I'm trying to convert it to utf8 because I want to read what the information is it sends out.

I do not have a lot of experience with this conversion issue. I did read a lot on it and got to a point where I can go from byte to hex but then I get stuck.
Below are a piece of code I've tried with one of the lines and the error I'm getting.
All guidance and help will be much appreciated.
code:

```
import codecs
msg = b'y\xbd\xd5\xdd\xb5\x9f\x0f}\x9f\x97\x8d\xe5\xebsQ\xed\x9d\x9d\x93\xe5\xebYu[\xb9\xedo]\x9d\x95\x97\x9bi\x99\x93KU\xe5\xebS\xed\x9d\x9b\x91\x9f\x9f\xe5\xebm\xed\x9f\x00y\xbd\xaa5\xd5\x99\x93\x97\x9f\x9f\xe5\xeb__S\xed\x9f\xe5\xebyY\xed\x9f\xe5\xebu[[\xed\x9f\xe5\xebo\x9d\x8d\xed\x95\x8d\x9d\x91\x8d\xe5\xebo\x9b\x9f\xed\x95\x95\xe5\xebo\x9b\x9d\xed\x99\x9f\x8d\x00y\xbdk\xb6\xd6\x95\x95\xe5\xebo\x9b\x99\xed\x9d\x93\x95\xe5\xeboYwY\xed\x8f\x99\xe5\xeby/59)\x19\x15%\xed\xfd\x00'
msg2 = msg.hex()
print(msg2)
msg3 = codecs.decode(msg2, "hex").decode('utf-8')
print(msg3)
```

error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbd in position 1: invalid start byte

Comment: That's not UTF-8.  It's not character data at all.  That's binary data.  You need to know what the content is.  It might be 16-bit integers, it might be floating point.  There's no way to know without the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802581/can-anyone-identify-this-encoding?rq=1) .

"This looks like binary data held in a Python bytes object. Loosely, bytes that map to printable ASCII characters are presented as those ASCII characters. All other bytes are encoded \x** where ** is the hex representation of the byte."

Which means a solution if you want to print the hex values would be something like this:

```
msg = b'y\xbd\xd5\xdd\xb5\x9f\x0f}\x9f\x97\x8d\xe5\xebsQ\xed\x9d\x9d\x93\xe5\xebYu[\xb9\xedo]\x9d\x95\x97\x9bi\x99\x93KU\xe5\xebS\xed\x9d\x9b\x91\x9f\x9f\xe5\xebm\xed\x9f\x00y\xbd\xaa5\xd5\x99\x93\x97\x9f\x9f\xe5\xeb__S\xed\x9f\xe5\xebyY\xed\x9f\xe5\xebu[[\xed\x9f\xe5\xebo\x9d\x8d\xed\x95\x8d\x9d\x91\x8d\xe5\xebo\x9b\x9f\xed\x95\x95\xe5\xebo\x9b\x9d\xed\x99\x9f\x8d\x00y\xbdk\xb6\xd6\x95\x95\xe5\xebo\x9b\x99\xed\x9d\x93\x95\xe5\xeboYwY\xed\x8f\x99\xe5\xeby/59)\x19\x15%\xed\xfd\x00'

# to string
msg = str(msg)

# print hex
for hex in msg:
    print(ord(hex))
```

Result:

```
98
39
121
92
120
98
100
92
120
100
53
92
120
100
100
92
120
98
53
92
120
57
102
92
120
48
102
125
92
120
57
102
92
120
57
55
92
120
56
100
92
120
101
53
92
120
101
98
115
81
92
120
101
100
92
120
57
100
92
120
57
100
92
120
57
51
92
120
101
53
92
120
101
98
89
117
91
92
120
98
57
92
120
101
100
111
93
92
120
57
100
92
120
57
53
92
120
57
55
92
120
57
98
105
92
120
57
57
92
120
57
51
75
85
92
120
101
53
92
120
101
98
83
92
120
101
100
92
120
57
100
92
120
57
98
92
120
57
49
92
120
57
102
92
120
57
102
92
120
101
53
92
120
101
98
109
92
120
101
100
92
120
57
102
92
120
48
48
121
92
120
98
100
92
120
97
97
53
92
120
100
53
92
120
57
57
92
120
57
51
92
120
57
55
92
120
57
102
92
120
57
102
92
120
101
53
92
120
101
98
95
95
83
92
120
101
100
92
120
57
102
92
120
101
53
92
120
101
98
121
89
92
120
101
100
92
120
57
102
92
120
101
53
92
120
101
98
117
91
91
92
120
101
100
92
120
57
102
92
120
101
53
92
120
101
98
111
92
120
57
100
92
120
56
100
92
120
101
100
92
120
57
53
92
120
56
100
92
120
57
100
92
120
57
49
92
120
56
100
92
120
101
53
92
120
101
98
111
92
120
57
98
92
120
57
102
92
120
101
100
92
120
57
53
92
120
57
53
92
120
101
53
92
120
101
98
111
92
120
57
98
92
120
57
100
92
120
101
100
92
120
57
57
92
120
57
102
92
120
56
100
92
120
48
48
121
92
120
98
100
107
92
120
98
54
92
120
100
54
92
120
57
53
92
120
57
53
92
120
101
53
92
120
101
98
111
92
120
57
98
92
120
57
57
92
120
101
100
92
120
57
100
92
120
57
51
92
120
57
53
92
120
101
53
92
120
101
98
111
89
119
89
92
120
101
100
92
120
56
102
92
120
57
57
92
120
101
53
92
120
101
98
121
47
53
57
41
92
120
49
57
92
120
49
53
37
92
120
101
100
92
120
102
100
92
120
48
48
39
```

Comment: thank you, I will read more on it and wait to see if I can get more info from the manufacturer, as I still do not know what to do with the data or how to translate it in to readable or functional data. Some will be a description and some values.